# How do I make a curved surface cube?

Tags: modeling

[image: I have been working to develop a Toro lantern, and I want to recreate the curved surface at the top, but for the past few hours I haven't found a good technique to replicate that. Any help would be appreciated I have scoured the internet looking for help, but no similar problem has been found.][image: This is the general curve I am looking for, but I want it to be a Cube and not a plane]

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: there are several ways to do it but if you create a cube and subdivide it you can choose the smoothness in the Operator box and it will round your cube.

Answer (score 3):

Add a plane.
Go to Edit mode.
Subdivide 3 times (press W> subdivide).
Select the center vertex.
Enable Proportional Editing (press O).
Press G, Z (to constrain to Z axis) and lift the vertex up.
   the mouse wheel controls how much influence Proportional Editing has

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was overly complicating it! I would have been stuck for hours before I even came across this possibility!

Answer (score 2):

Select a cube in Edit Mode (create some extra faces by using subdivide). Mesh > Transform > To Sphere

If you want fo use one of the "inner sides" as a basis for a japanese style roof, make sure to fix the normals by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> before you finish your project.

[image]